# Machine learning in skewed data

Tags: machine-learning, skew

I am training a neural network on an emotion recognition dataset for five classes of emotion.  I some problems:

1. The dataset set is skewed: class1 has 100 observations, but class2 has 3000.

   I tried to use Smote to balance the data.
2. The training data is not similar to the testing data; that is a big problem.

I don't know how to solve problem 2; please help me.

Comment: What do you mean the testing data is not similar to the training data?

Is there a way to normalize the data ?

Comment: What constitutes a solution to your problem?  How are the data sets "not similar"?  What options do you have to change the data sets?